# Laravel 5 PHP Domdocument 400 Bad request

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, domdocument, bad-request

I get a `file_get_contents(https://soundcloud.com/50_cent/im-the-man-ft-sonny-digital): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request`

I want to use domdocument laravel 5.1 to get title and content id from a soundcloud url.

It worked fine with a youtube url and a vimeo url but with soundcloud it won't work.

The url I'm using is:
https://soundcloud.com/50_cent/im-the-man-ft-sonny-digital
just for testing.

This is my code to get the title and content id:

```
                $doc = new \DOMDocument();
                $doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($input_url));
                $title = $doc->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->nodeValue;

                $tags = get_meta_tags($input_url);
                $link_id = $tags['content'];
                DB::table('content_add')->insert([
                    [
                        'url' => $input_url,
                        'title' => $title,
                        'link_id'=> $link_id,
                        'type' => $type,
                        'user_id'=> Auth::id(),
                        'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
                    ],
                ]);
```

At the end I just add it to a database.
Also when using `urlencode()` I get this error `file_get_contents(https%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2Fgracedmusic%2Fhello-adele): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it will help if you create a [stream context](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) for the [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and pass the [ignore_errors](http://cz.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php#context.http.ignore-errors) option set to `true`.

```
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$input_url = "https://soundcloud.com/50_cent/im-the-man-ft-sonny-digital";
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'ignore_errors' => true,
        'user_agent' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($input_url, false, $context));
$title = $doc->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Then you can get the meta tags by checking the attributes. If you for example want the number from the 'twitter:app:url:googleplay' property:

```
$link_id = '';
$startsWith = 'soundcloud://sounds:';

foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName("meta") as $meta) {
    if ($meta->hasAttribute('property') && $meta->getAttribute('property') === 'twitter:app:url:googleplay') {
        $link_id = $meta->getAttribute('content');
        if (substr($link_id, 0, strlen($startsWith))) {
            $link_id = substr($link_id, strlen($startsWith), strlen($link_id));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but with the meta tag takes only tha last content I want the one with the numbers in it. I get https://soundcloud.com

Comment: @MarijnRutten There are mulitple meta tags which contain numbers. Do you know the name of the property you are looking for? For example: `property="fb:app_id"` or `property="twitter:app:id:iphone"`? Or perhaps do you mean this one? `name="google-site-verification"`?

Comment: I'm looking for the number in in this `content="soundcloud://sounds:236014320"` content attribute which is in many meta tags on the page.

Comment: @MarijnRutten I've updated my answer and filtered the number from the meta property 'twitter:app:url:googleplay'.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for helping me! I had problems with `:` and `-` `strpos()` and `substr()` wouldn't work with these